# How to Change Column Names?

Tags: r

The names of the columns in my data frame all have the same format. All the column names/vector names start "jjk_" and then read the correct name of the column. Here is how it looks:

```
jjk_LEFT.       jjk_COLD.      jjk_TOP
4                  7              55
6                  12             3
7                  23             6
...
```

All I want to do is remove the "jjk_" so that the column names just read all that follows after the underscore. Thus, I would like the final data frame to look like this:

```
LEFT.       COLD.     TOP
4            7         55
6            12        3
7            23        6
...
```

Comment: `colnames(df) = gsub("jjk_", "", colnames(df))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
colnames(df) = gsub("jjk_", "", colnames(df))

#     LEFT. COLD. TOP
# 1     4     7  55
# 2     6    12   3
# 3     7    23   6

structure(list(jjk_LEFT. = c(4L, 6L, 7L), 
               jjk_COLD. = c(7L, 12L, 23L),
               jjk_TOP = c(55L, 3L, 6L)), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L)) -> df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `setNames` with `gsub`

```
setNames(df,gsub("^\\w+_","",names(df)))
```

which gives

```
  LEFT. COLD. TOP
1     4     7  55
2     6    12   3
3     7    23   6
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(jjk_LEFT. = c(4L, 6L, 7L), jjk_COLD. = c(7L, 12L, 
23L), jjk_TOP = c(55L, 3L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `trimws` from `base R`

```
names(df) <- trimws(names(df), whitespace = '^\\w+_')
names(df)
#[1] "LEFT." "COLD." "TOP"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(jjk_LEFT. = c(4L, 6L, 7L), jjk_COLD. = c(7L, 12L, 
23L), jjk_TOP = c(55L, 3L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```